# Data Grid View, phantom column

Tags: c#

I have a data grid view in c# for a basic crossword game. To the left of the first column, titled "#" is a space, I can't seem to remove it, it is defiantly not a column that is recognized by Visual Studio... I just want to get rid of it.

[image]

Comment: Funny. that's a default column number space. remove your # column and take advantage of default functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a default column number space. remove your `#` column and take advantage of default functionality

Answer (score 0):

Its was a default column number space, as user RadioSpace helpfully pointed out!!!